# Use one controller CREATE method for multiple pages ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, crud

I have multiple models that get update in my database. Each model, like tasks, vendors, and invoicing is tied to a single job. When I create and edit one of these models (using the corresponding CRUD page), I want it to open up a create/edit page for all available models. For example, if I create a new job site, I also want the option to add in vendors, tasks, etc. If I edit a job site, I also want the option to edit all of the other models. As it stands, getting the details of these models to display as one page was simple. Getting the create function to work in the same way is more difficult. Is it possible to use one of my controller's create method to serve as a create method for another controller/model? Is it possible to do the same thing for the Edit and Delete functions? Here is what my controller looks like for the Create method.

```
// GET: Towers/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Towers/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,SiteId,SiteName,TowerHeight,TowerType,TaskOrder,Street,City,State,Zip,CrossStreet,Latitude,Longitude,Notes,StartDate,EndDate,ParsonsPm,ParsonsRe,DecomCrewNum,ActualStartDate,ActualEndDate")] Tower tower)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(tower);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(tower);
        }
```

And the CREATE method for the Vendor controller (I haven't edited it from what `dotnet` scaffolds)

```
// GET: Vendors/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["TowerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Tower, "Id", "Id");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Vendors/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("VendorId,CraneVendor,CranePhone,PortableToiletVendor,PortableToiletPhone,ForkliftVendor,ForkliftPhone,SkidSteerVendor,SkidSteerPhone,ExcavatorVendor,ExcavatorPhone,LoaderVendor,LoaderPhone,SteelDumpstersVendor,SteelDumpstersPhone,ConcreteDumpstersVendor,ConcreteDumpstersPhone,CraneCallOffNum,CraneOnRent,CraneOffRent,PortableToiletOnRent,PortableToiletOffRent,ForkliftOnRent,ForkliftOffRent,SkidSteerOnRent,SkidSteerOffRent,ExcavatorOnRent,ExcavatorOffRent,LoaderOnRent,LoaderOffRent,SteelDumpstersOnRent,SteelDumpstersOffRent,ConcreteDumpstersOnRent,ConcreteDumpstersOffRent,ForkliftCallOffNum,SkidSteerCallOffNum,ExcavatorCallOffNum,LoaderCallOffNum,SteelDumpsterCallOffNum,ConcreteDumpsterCallOffNum,TowerId")] Vendor vendor)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(vendor);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["TowerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Tower, "Id", "Id", vendor.TowerId);
            return View(vendor);
        }
```

For reference, this my DETAILS method in my `TowerController`

```
// GET: Towers/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var tower = await _context.Tower
                .Include(v => v.Vendor)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (tower == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(tower);
        }
```

You can see that it also includes the details of the relevant vendors for the particular site.

Comment: You mean that you want to call 1 action, and then it will return many views, right?

Comment: @Tomato32 What I want is for one create method from one controller be used for multiple controllers if that makes sense. Like as it stands, I have one controller that handles CRUD for each model, and I would like to have one controller handle CRUD for all models.